# bootstrap4 navbar set active link

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4, navigation, navbar

I have a navbar that has a line below nav-item and shows that the item is active. I have got the snippet long time ago and dont have the source. I want to change it such that when user clicks on it, the line stays on the nav-item. Right now it appears on hover. It uses the :hover which triggers some transform and more style. What class should I add such that with jquery to make it work?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm"> <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-target="#navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item"> <a href="{% url 'terminal-management'  %}" class="nav-link"> Terminals </a> </li>
                <li class="nav-item"> <a href="{% url 'location-management'  %}" class="nav-link active"> Area & Rooms </a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

css

```
/*Admin employee navbar */
.nav-item::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #233242;
  transition: 0.4s
}

.nav-item:hover {
  color:black;
}

.nav-item:hover::after {
  width: 100%
}

.nav-item {

  color:#233242;
}

.nav-link {
  padding: 25px 5px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  color:#233242;
}
.nav-link:hover {
  color:#233242;
}

html {
  overflow: hidden !important;
  background-color: black;
}

.image-td {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
/*Admin employee navbar */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#nav) says:

> Active states—with .active—to indicate the current page can be applied
> directly to .nav-links or their immediate parent .nav-items.

So you need to place `active` class on `nav-item` to make it work. Like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm"> <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-target="#navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active"> <a href="{% url 'terminal-management'  %}" class="nav-link"> Terminals </a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item"> <a href="{% url 'location-management'  %}" class="nav-link active"> Area & Rooms </a> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Probably you won't need to define a custom style to it, but you can using this css selector:

```
.nav-link.active {
  color: red;
}
```